# Storing edges in OrientDb in ordered way

Tags: orientdb

I am working with OrientDB graph API using java API and Gremlin Pipeline. I wanted to know is there a way to specify storing order for edges based on an attribute? I know we can create a custom edge type and define index on the attribute based upon which we want to retrieve.
I also had a look at the tutorial on the OrientDB website:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#ordered-edges

There they do mention that edges can be retrieved in an ordered way but they dont mention how is the order determined.So I would like to know:

What is the default storage order?And will fetching from this order give me edges in an LIFO format?

How can we store based on custom order i.e. store in the order in which we want it to be fetched?

Comment: That link to the docs isn't pointing to ordered edges anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying type used is a List, so the order is the inserting order. To change it, get the edge list, work on it and then call `vertex.save()` where vertex is casted to OrientVertex.